# jquery concatenate variable and string

Tags: jquery

i need contenate with jquery a variable with string
this is my example code:

```
 $("#totriepilogoassegni").html(msg);
```

After msg i need insert "euro" or "€".

How can fix it ?

Best Regards
Andrea

Comment: what type is **msg**? How is it calcualted?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `concatenation` **+** operator to concat string to a variable.

```
$("#totriepilogoassegni").html(msg + ' euro');

$("#totriepilogoassegni").html(msg + ' €');
```

**Using Append**

```
$("#totriepilogoassegni").html(msg).append(' euro');
```

Comment: this may be correct or incorrect depending on what type **msg** itself is

Comment: @AmmarCSE `msg` will be text, I think

Comment: exactly, you **think** :)

Comment: nice one ;). Like the creativity

Answer (score 1):

You can create a js method for reuse it:

```
function currencyAppender(msg, curr){
    return msg +' '+curr;
}
```

then you can use it this way:

```
$("#totriepilogoassegni").html(currencyAppender(msg, 'euro'));
```

---

This way you can use it for multiple currencies.